# ¿Mostrar datos de una API mediante JSON en HTML?

Tags: html, json, api

Ojala me puedan ayudar, ya que nunca he trabajado con un un `.JSON`, `API`, tengo una `URL` de una `API` que me devuelve los siguientes datos, ejemplo:

```
{"Anio":"2019","totMaestros":"47","totGraduados":"3243","totGrupos":"442"}
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo mostrar los datos en una vista `html` con `JSON`, ejemplo:

**Año actual: 2019**

**Total de maestros: 47**

En la consola me muestra estos datos:

```
{Anio: "2019", totMaestros: "47", totGraduados: "3243", totGrupos: "442"}
Anio: "2019"
FechaUltimaMod: "2019-08-16 12:54:42.000"
totGraduados: "3243"
totGrupos: "442"
totMaestros: "47"
```

espero me puedan ayudar ya que no se como resolverlo, saludos.

Comment: Usas JS o jQuery? Edita por favor e indícanos más detalles al respecto por favor

Comment: @Aprendiz con JS o como seria mas optimo?

Comment: Eso depende, ojalá nos puedas mostrar tu avance y sobre ese partir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haz lo siguiente. en el HTML donde quieres mostrar los datos identificalos con un ID

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Mostrar JSON desde AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Año actual: <span id="iAnoActual"></span></p>
    <p>Total de maestros: <span id="iTotalMaestros"></span></p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.get('http://sitio.com/api/endpoint/method',function(data){
                var dJson = JSON.parse(data);
                $('#iAnoActual').text(dJson.AnioDePadron);
                $('#iTotalMaestros').text(dJson.totGraduados);
            });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Al usar el metodo **$.get('url',function(data){})** la variable **data** para a contener el valor de la API y puedes consultar el objeto como **data.valor_en_el_objeto**. Se tuvo que usar el metodo **JSON.parse()** porque la URL no responde como un JSON valido.

Comment: Me cargo una vez, pero pude recuperar los datos. Prueba con la actualización del código que coloque.

Comment: Gil muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para poder mostrar resultados JSON en tu HTML debes usar un poco de codigo `javascript` y la técnica [AJAX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) que consisten en realizar peticiones Asíncronas a un servicio web con javascript.

Son varios pasos pero con practica los aprenderás porque son casi siempre los mismos:

1. Primero importa la librería `Jquery` de [aquí](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery).
2. Crea un `input` para escribir la busqueda y un `botton` para buscar
3. Crear una `<tabla id="respuesta">` para mostrar la respuesta.
4. Crear un `<script>` al final del `<body>` que llame al metodo `$.ajax()`.
5. Al metodo `$.ajax()` le pasas la URL que te regresa el Json.
6. En el cuerpo del `done` del metodo `ajax` crear el `<tr>` y pintas la respuesta.

Aquí un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- 1. importas la libreria jquery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- 2. crear el formularo en html -->
    
    <input id="usuario" placeholder="Escribe 1 o 2 o 3">
    <button onclick="buscar()">buscar</button>
    
    <!-- 3. crer la tabla en html -->
    
    <table id="respuesta">
        <thead>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Nombre de Usuario</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="respuesta_body">
        </tbody>
    </table>
   
</body>

<!--  4. agrega el script final del body -->
<script>

// 5. crear metodo buscar 
function buscar(){
  
  // 6. obtene el valor del <input id="usuario">
  let usuario = $('#usuario').val()
  
  $.ajax({
    
    // 7. agrega el valor a la url
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"+usuario
  
  }).done(function(data) {
     
     
     // 8. construyes el <tr> con tus datos de respuesta
     let tr = '<tr>'+
          '<td>' + data.id + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + data.email + '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
     console.log(tr) // *opcional para ver en consola
     
     // 9. usas append para agregar el tr al final
     $('#respuesta_body').append(tr)
  
  });
}
</script>
</html>
```